# Does Docker volume copy the files or just mount the folder?

Tags: docker

I want to be able to use files from the host filesystem in my Docker container.  I only want a mount point; I don't want the files to be copied into the container.  So I am adding several lines like this to my Dockerfile: "RUN -v /opt/P01_SH/_Library:/opt/P01_SH/_Library."  The container will refer to the directory by the same name.

According to "Populate a volume using a container" at   https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes:   "If you start a container which creates a new volume, and the container has files or directories in the directory to be mounted such as /app/, Docker copies the directory's contents into the volume. The container then mounts and uses the volume, and other containers which use the volume also have access to the pre-populated content."

I read that to mean that if I use -v then all the files will be copied into the container.  Is my interpretation of that comment correct?  Should I use mount instead to mount the volumes in the container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `docker run -v /host/path:/container/path`, the Docker [bind mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/bind-mounts/) mechanism means that the host and container files are literally the same.  Files aren't "copied" into the container, instead the same filesystem exists on the host path and container path.  This is the same behavior as non-Docker plain-Linux `mount --bind`.

(A side note that this is only really actually true directly running the Docker engine on native Linux.  If you're using Docker Desktop or another VM-based solution, the files also need to propagate between the host system and the Docker-Linux VM, and this can cause some inconsistencies.)

You refer to a different rule about Docker [named volumes](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/).  That rule can be subtle, and is often misinterpreted as named or anonymous volumes providing an exception to a mount that passes through to the original image, or as a way to publish one image's content to another container.  The syntax you show uses Docker bind mounts and not named volumes, and nothing is ever automatically copied into a bind-mounted directory.  (...nor a Kubernetes PersistentVolumeClaim, nor any other sort of storage beyond very specifically Docker named volumes, and older volume content will overwrite updates in an image; I'd argue it's a mistake to rely on this volume behavior.)

> I am adding several lines like this to my Dockerfile: "RUN -v ..."

You can never specify host directories in a Dockerfile.  You don't need to do anything in the Dockerfile to make it possible to mount a host directory over parts of the container.  Newer Docker does include a `RUN --mount` option, but that is only for specialized use cases, and the mount details do not get persisted beyond that specific `RUN` step.

> I want to be able to use files from the host filesystem...

A key original design goal of Docker is that containers can't access the host filesystem; bind mounts break that rule.  If the primary purpose of your application is to read or write host files, you'll probably find it substantially easier to run without a container isolation layer.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Your last comment confuses me.  I need to run this in a container for portability and security.  All I want to do is (1) read certain data from the host filesystem, and (2) write some files to the host filesystem.  The reason is because the container would become too large with the 1GB+ datafiles I work with.  You say the syntax I used would create unwanted "bind mounts" but the flag is RUN -v for volume.  Your answer leaves me uncertain as to what I put in my Dockerfile to create these volumes.

Comment: If I use named volumes, would the data be duplicated into the volumes?  I ask because I work with very large datafiles.  Are named volumes the preferred choice?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can `docker run -v` when you launch a container, but the Dockerfile can't specify that the eventual container will have access to a specific host directory (there is not Dockerfile `RUN -v` syntax).  For something like what you're describing, if you can't use a reasonably portable language/runtime for your application (Java or Python run more or less everywhere with few tweaks, with carefully written code) then a Docker bind mount is correct; nothing is copied; and the host directory always completely replaces whatever might have been in the image at that directory.

Comment: You say, "the host directory always completely replaces" -- if there is no instruction in the code to write to a bind location, then I don't think it would replace anything.  Please correct me if that's incorrect.  I would be surprised to see my data replaced unless I had code to do that.

Comment: The thing the standard relational-database images do is to include an empty directory in the image, assuming something will be mounted there, and initialize the data directory on startup if it's empty.